# Find the number of different colorings of the faces of the cube with 2 white, 1 black, 3 red faces?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, permutations, polya-counting-theory

I tried using Polya theorem same in this https://nosarthur.github.io/math%20and%20physics/2017/08/10/polya-enumeration.html guide, using S4 group for cube faces. But i Have a $\frac{1}{24}12w^2*b*r^3$.
Please help to me how count coloring faces of the cube and other platonic solids.

Comment: Symmetry group of cube faces has 24 elements but is not S4.

Comment: @Wuestenfux You are incorrect; the rotational symmetry group of the cube IS isomorphic to $S_4$. http://www.ams.org/publicoutreach/feature-column/fcarc-cubes7#:~:text=In%20an%20analogous%20way%2C%20the,%2C%20however%2C%20has%2048%20elements.

Comment: In order for us to show you where you went wrong, you need to show your word. For starters, what is the cycle index polynomial you are using?

Comment: @Wuestenfux You can see it's S4 if you consider its action on the body diagonals of the cube. Any permutation of the four diagonals is possible.

Comment: Ahh, thank you. This is good to known.

Answer (score 2):

The cycle index polynomial for rotational symmetries of the faces of a cube is
$$
\tfrac1{24}(z_1^6+12z_2^3+8z_3^2+3z_1^2z_2^2)
$$
Therefore, in order to count the number of colorings with one black, three red, and two white faces, we need to find the coefficient $b^1r^3w^2$ in
$$
\tfrac1{24}[(b+w+r)^6+12(b^2+r^2+w^2)^3+8(b^3+r^3+w^3)^2+3(b+r+w)^2(b^2+r^2+w^2)^2]
$$
Going term by term...

- The coeficient of $b^1r^3w^2$ in $(b+r+w)^6$ is given by the multinomial coefficient $\binom{6!}{1!3!2!}=60$.
- $(b^2+r^2+w^2)^3$ contributes nothing to $b^1r^3w^2$.
- $(b^3+r^3+w^3)^2$ also contributes nothing.
- The trickiest term is $(b+r+w)^2(b^2+r^2+w^2)^2$. I will write this as
  $$
  (b+r+w)(b+r+w)(b^2+r^2+w^2)(b^2+r^2+w^2)
  $$
  In order to contribute to $b^1r^3w^2$, the $(b^2+r^2+w^2)$ factors need to contribute an $r^2$ and a $w^2$. This can be done in either order, for $2$ choices. The remaining $b^1r^1$ comes from the $(b+r+w)$ factors; again, either one can give the $b$ while the other gives an $r$, for another $2$ choices. Therefore, the contribution from this term is $2\times 2=4$.

All in all, the coefficient is
$$
\frac1{24}[1\cdot 60+12\cdot 0+8\cdot 0+3\cdot 4]=\boxed{3}
$$

Here is a [Wolfram Alpha computation which confirms this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Coefficient%5B%28%28b+%2B+w+%2B+r%29%5E6+%2B+12%28b%5E2+%2B+r%5E2+%2B+w%5E2%29%5E3+%2B+8+%28b%5E3+%2B+r%5E3+%2B+w%5E3%29%5E2+%2B+3+%28b+%2B+r+%2B+w%29%5E2+%28b%5E2+%2B+r%5E2+%2B+w%5E2%29%5E2%29%2F24%2C++b+r%5E3+w%5E2%5D).

Comment: I think your cycle index is wrong

Comment: The answer is correct but acc to Wikipedia $S_4$ cycle index is different

Answer (score 1):

For this we can use the Burnside lemma, a simpler version of the Pólya theorem.  We consider the five conjugacy classes of symmetries of the cube and for each symmetry we count the number of colorings o the cube left *fixed* by the symmetry.  Consider the black face.  For a coloring to be left fixed by some symmetry, the black face must be left fixed.  This rules out the rotations where the axis goes through a vertex or an edge of the cube, since those fix no faces.  So we need only consider:

1. The identity symmetry leaves fixed all $\frac{6!}{3!2!1!} = 60$ colorings of the cube.
2. There are 6 rotations by 90° around an axis through a face of the cube.  These divide the faces into orbits of sizes $4, 1, 1$.  There is no way for such a rotation to leave the three red faces fixed.
3. There are 3 rotations by 180° around an axis through a face of the cube.  These divide the cube into orbits of sizes $2, 2, 1, 1$.  For one of these rotations to leave the coloring unchanged, The black face must be in one of the two orbits of size $1$ and the white faces in one of the two orbits of size $2$.  There are $2·2=4$ ways to do this and then the red faces are in the other two orbits.

The total is $$\frac1{24}\left(\underbrace{60}_{\text{identity}} + 
\underbrace{6·0}_{90°} + \underbrace{3·4}_{180°}\right) = 3.$$

Note that this calculation is completely analogous to the one done by Mike Earnest elsewhere in the thread.